# No E-Mail issue with user invitations

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, outgoing-email

I am new to sharepoint, I installed it and I created a new site and subsites. Now, I want to add users to the site, I added a user, it's added successfully but no invitation email is sent to the user, so I want to know if there are any settings that I have to do to enable that? or what is wrong with me?

Waiting your help and reply, and Thank You

Comment: Does your farm have the email services enabled?

Comment: How to know if it is enabled or not?

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure the outgoing email settings inside Central Administration.

Following guide should assist you!

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34167.sharepoint-2016-outgoing-email-configuration-settings.aspx#Configure_using_the_Central_Admin

You may also take a look at the following thread:-

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3b5fd5de-b2fe-4a56-8fd7-0e18f1bba270/sharepoint-2016-email-notifications-do-not-work?forum=SP2016

Comment: Ah Yes I did this,,

Comment: updated answer - hope that helps